# Styling scrollbar for google chrome browser

Tags: css

I'm trying to share some knowledge by posting some css tricks questions(and jquery tricks in another topics) and answer it.
Here I'm dealing with styling the scrollbar for google chrome browser.

Answer (score 26):

Just add these CSS rules:

1. `::-webkit-scrollbar`
2. `::-webkit-scrollbar-button`
3. `::-webkit-scrollbar-track`
4. `::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece`
5. `::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb`
6. `::-webkit-scrollbar-corner`
7. `::-webkit-resizer`

Here's what each rule does:
[image]

Answer (score 8):

Here is a simple example of a customized scrollbar using css

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
    border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}
```

Here is how it will look.

[image]

ref: https://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/