# How to make thin scrollbar in chrome?

Tags: html, css, sass

I have make thin scrollbar in Firefox for this css:

```
  scrollbar-width: thin;
  scrollbar-color: rgba(155, 155, 155, 0.5) transparent;
```

it's worked for firefox.

Now i need to make thin scrollbar in chrome.
I have tried this css

```
*-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 9px;
}
*-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: transparent;
}
*-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: rgba(155, 155, 155, 0.5);
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: transparent;
}
```

But this code does not work in chrome.

Any suggestion please.

Comment: Looks like you need to replace `*` with `::`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17480087/styling-scrollbar-for-google-chrome-browser

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try this:-

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 9px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: transparent;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: rgba(155, 155, 155, 0.5);
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: transparent;
}
```

Comment: To customize horizontal scrollbars too, set `height: 9px`. More details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44334106/how-can-i-style-horizontal-scrollbar-by-css

Answer (score -4):

chrome://flags/
Overlay Scrollbars = Enabled

Comment: That would require each user setting the chrome flags themselves, which is not a viable solution.

Comment: This is the only answer I expected to find. So upvote anyway:)

Comment: Doesn't work in other browsers